# Pytest bdd cucumber - fetching examples table from excel or csv file

Tags: python, pytest-bdd, cucumber-python

Cucmber BDD - Is there anyway to link the Examples datatable of a Scenario Outline with an external excel file directly from  the Feature file in the pytest framework?